# Getting javascript generated line breaks to display in div update

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

I've managed to get my javascript to update the text in a div when I click on something.  So that's cool.  However, it doesn't transmit any of the linebreaks to the div.  I think it's because my javascript code is trying to give input that is mis-matched with the content type of the div, or maybe a div is the wrong thing to use.  This is my first js effort ever so not really sure what to try next.

Any advice appreciated!

Here is the .js code:

```
var container=document.getElementById("feedbacktext");
while (container.childNodes.length>=1) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
}               container.appendChild(container.ownerDocument.createTextNode(txtline));
```

Here is the div which it targets.  The line breaks to not show as text in the div text when updated, and do not take any effect either:

```
<div id="feedbacktext" style="height:200px;width:960px;overflow:auto;text-align:left;" type="text/html">
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is that HTML does not display 'enters' as newlines. You did not show a sample input, so I cannot confirm this, but if this is true, the solution would be adding a `<br>` tag instead of an enter.

Also, you can empty the container in a faster way, using innerHTML.

```
container.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: @user1844086 Glad to be able to help. For the next time it would be a good idea to give some sample input.